# AWS Lambda doesn't work with `async`, Only with callbacks?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function in AWS using Node 8.1 which initiate MSSQL request ( to an external server , which is not in aws)

When I'm using the non `async`  handler with non async code (but callbacks )—

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {...}
```

— Everything is OK.

Proof: For this code, which uses callbacks-

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     sql.connect(config, err => {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        } else {
          const req = new sql.Request();
          req.query(
            'select * from img.dbo.images where imageid = 1641',
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                callback(error);
              } else {
                sql.close();
                callback(null, result.recordset);
              }
            }
          );
        }
      });
};
```

I get this response :

[image]

**However** , If I change the code [*to the async version*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait) :

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let result1 = await pool
      .request()
      .query('select * from img.dbo.images where imageid = 1641');

    callback(null, result1.recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    callback(err);
  }
};
```

— I get a Timeout error(sure it's related to a non-fulfill promise) :

[image]

**Question**

Why doesn't the `async`  version work ? how can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the callback param and just return the result instead. Also, you can avoid catching errors unless you need to do any special handling

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const pool = await sql.connect(config);
  return await pool
    .request()
    .query('select * from img.dbo.images where imageid = 1641');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. working. One question though , When an error occurs , should I `return` it ? or should I `callback(error)` it ?  can you please provide a small example in this ^ code ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir forget `callback()` with `async` / `await`, if you want to catch the error then you should return it.

Comment: thanks for this,  i never came across anything offical to return request/response instead of using callback so was stuck as well